# doing ODBC System DSN's from Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, oracle, odbc

2008R2 Active Directory, workstations are Win7 Ent, Office/Excel 2013, Oracle 11.2.  Excel fetches data from Oracle using System DSN's.

Where can I put ODBC System DSN's in Active Directory?  Do I need to do anything special to the Win7 / Excel 2013 so that it can fetch System DSN's from AD rather than locally?

Thanks,

Comment: Deploy the ODBC DSNs using Group Policy. There seems to be a bug so it has to be done by deploying the registry entries directly.

Comment: oh swell. Isn't that just special.  Anyway, thanks!